# Pending changes in AnkhSVN only shows files from current solution

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I'm working under a single repository and mostly in one solution.
However, during the work on the solution I do change other files as well, when I come to commit, however, AnkhSVN only shows the files that are part of the solution. That forces me to use TortoiseSVN to do the commit on the whole directory, which in turn misses some of the files that I added with AnkhSVN.

The simplest solution to this would be if AnkhSVN showed me ALL the pending changes for the repository. A worse alternative would be if AnkhSVN flagged added files so that TortoiseSVN would be also aware to them when doing commit from it.

Anyone knows a solution to these issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set an option to auto add files when new files are created that should be versioned by going to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion Environment. Select "Directly add new files to Subversion" here.

Another alternative to make "New" files "Added" is the "Apply to Working Copy" command, available through the drop down next to the Commit button in the Pending Changes window.

Comment: Can't believe I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseSVN, there's a checkbox in the commit dialog "show unversioned items". If you check that box, the files that are not added yet are shown as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the svn folder then TortoiseSVN-->Add , will show all the items which is not included for supervision.

[check the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txXRF.png)