# AnkhSvn is not adding subfolders of my solution automatically

Tags: c#, svn, ankhsvn

My AnkhSvn is not adding solution folders automatically to svn. So ... if i add files to the solution folder these don't get added as well.

Any ideas? Thank you so much

I am using Visual Studio 2013 prof

Answer (score 2):

Try this: "You can set an option to auto add files when new files are created that should be versioned by going to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Subversion Environment. Select "Directly add new files to Subversion" here."

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782513/1023562